# How can I raise the discoverer limit in AWS EventBridge so more than 10?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shopify, aws-event-bridge

I currently have ten discoverers for EventBridge in one AWS account. When I go to create another discoverer I get this error:

```
The limit has been reached for total number of Discoverers. The current limit is 10.
```

How do I increase the limit to above 10? If it helps these event busses and discoverers are coming from the Shopify partner event source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [AWS Service Quotas](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/schemas/quotas) and request `Discoverers` limit increasing.

**＊`Discoverers` limit may be set separately per region. My link is pointing to `us-east-1` region. Don't forget to switch it into your actual region before creating request**

Comment: Thanks! That's the page I've been looking for.